# put ignore rules there

Tags: gitignore

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, выполняю упражнения на сайте http://gitexercises.fracz.com/exercise/ignore-them, дошла до команды ignore-them. В задании указано добавить 
    all files with exe extension
    all files with o extension
    all files with jar extension
    the whole libraries directory
Я создала файл touch .gitignore , а что дальше делать не пойму. В подсказке указывается создать .gitignore, а затем сказано добавить правила, а КАК ЭТО СДЕЛАТЬ? - я не пойму
You need to create a .gitignore file, put ignore rules there and commit it.
Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: это русский сайт. рекомендуется использовать русский язык. переведите свой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Открываете .gitignore любым текстовым редактором (не Word) и добавляете в него правила, по одному на строку. Затем сохраняете. Например, игнорировать все файлы с расширением exe и com

```
*.exe
*.com
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все оказалось очень просто! Да надо было просто открыть редактор и вставить все исключения!!! Спасибо!!

Comment: исправьте (переведите) вопрос и примите ответ